# Uso de async y await en una función que controla un guard

Tags: angular, firebase

Tengo un "guard" que llama a una función en un servicio para comprobar si el usuario está logeado.

El servicio tiene esta función que he configurado como **async** porque dentro hay un **await** que espera a que "**onAuthStateChanged**" termine de hacer una consulta y devuelve el valor de **valor control**. Por lo que veo si no pusiese el **async**, el **return** tendría lugar antes de que **onAuthStateChanged** terminase y no devolvería el valor correcto. **(No sé si esta es la mejor forma de hacer esto)**

```javascript
async comprobarAutentificacion() {
        let valorControl:boolean = true;
        await  this.angularFireAuth.onAuthStateChanged( user =>{
          if(user) {  
            valorControl = true;  
          } else {
            valorControl = false; 
          }
        });
        return valorControl;
}
```

Luego, en el guard tengo este código:

```javascript
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private servicio: MiservicioService, private router: Router){}
      private valorRetorno: boolean =false;
      canActivate(): boolean{ 
        this.servicio.comprobarAutentificacion().then( valor =>{
             this.valorRetorno = valor;
        }); 
        if(this.valorRetorno) {
            console.log("COMPROBAMOS: " + this.valorRetorno);
            return true;
        } else {
           console.log("Redirigimosssss: ");
           this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
           return false;
        }
      }  
}
```

En el guard, lo primero que hago es llamar la función **comprobarAutentificacion** del servicio que de arriba que al ser una función **async** devuelve una promesa que recojo con un **then()**. En el cuerpo del then lo que hago es asigar el valor a la variable **valorRetorno **.

Justo después lo que hago es comprobar con un IF  dicha variable y retornar un true o false que recoge la ruta especificada en el archivo de rutas. Creo que este if no está bien pq puede que ejecute antes que la llamada a **this.servicio.comprobarAutentificacion()** al ser todo asíncrono en este bloque de cófigo. Podría hacer que esta función del guard fuese Async y la llamada al servicio fuese con un awair, peor me devlvería una promesa y esta función no puede devolver promesas para que el archivo de rutas funcione. ¿Es así?¿ cómo puedo mejorar esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problema

Tu guard no está manejando correctamente la llamada a `this.servicio.comprobarAutentificacion()` ya que es una función asíncrona.

```js
private valorRetorno: boolean = false;

canActivate(): boolean{   
    this.servicio.comprobarAutentificacion().then( valor =>{
        this.valorRetorno = valor;
    });
    
     if(this.valorRetorno) { // <- aquí 'this.valorRetorno' sigue siendo false como cuando se declaró. Ya que la línea anterior solo dispara la ejecución de la promesa 'comprobarAutentificacion()'.
        console.log("COMPROBAMOS: " + this.valorRetorno);
        return true;
     } else { // Por lo que siempre entrará por el else ya que es 'false'
       console.log("Redirigimosssss: ");
       this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
       return false;
     }
}
```

### Solución

Para solucionar esto, [canActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) puede devolver una Promesa o un Observable.

Esto sería:

```js
canActivate(): Promise<boolean> | boolean{   
    return this.servicio.comprobarAutentificacion().then(valor =>{
        this.valorRetorno = valor;
        if(this.valorRetorno) { // <- aquí 'this.valorRetorno' es igual a 'valor' podrías usar directamente el parámetro 'valor'
           console.log("COMPROBAMOS: " + this.valorRetorno);
           return true; // acá en el "futuro" se resolverá la promesa y Angular sabrá si puede o no activar la ruta
       } else {
          console.log("Redirigimosssss: ");
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          return false; // acá en el "futuro" se resolverá la promesa y Angular sabrá si puede o no activar la ruta
     }
    });
}
```

De esta forma le dices a Angular que el `guard` [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) se resolverá asincrónicamente y que espere a su resolución.

Comment: Muy buena explicación.

Comment: Pero tengo una duda con respeto a eso que pones de "Promise<boolean> | boolean".  intuyo que es algo que inica que : a= o bien retorna una promesa con un boolean... o b) retorna directamente un boolean . Es algo así?

Comment: Si, creo que funciona sin el "| boolean"