# función asíncrona que devuelve una promesa a una función "normal". Dicha función normal debe devolver un boolean

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función **async** cuyo nombre es **conseguirDatos()**. En dicha función:

- Se llaman a dos promesas en orden (van con **await**)
- Una vez que terminan las dos promesas precedidas por **await()** se hace el rerturn. Se supone que dicha función **async** devuelve una promesa.

```javascript
   function async conseguirDatos() {
        const nombre = await this.miservicio.getNombre();
        const apellido = await this.miservicio.getApellido();

        return("nombre: " + nombre + " " + "apellido: " + apellido);
   }
```

Después tengo otra función normal cuyo nombre es **llamada** que debe retornar un boolean después de comprobar el estado. Esta función por necesidad tiene quye devolverme un boolean (por otros motivos que aquí no expongo), por lo tanto no le puedo poner un **async** delante. Lo que debe hacer es

```javascript
 function llamada() {
        this.conseguirDatos().then((valor)=>{
          console.log("mostrando valor: " + valor);

          if(valor!=null){
            return true;

          }else
          {
            return false;
          }

        });

  }
```

:Mis preguntas son:

-Cómo y dónde debo poner el return dentro de la función **llamada** : dentro den "then" o fuera? previamente debo asegurarme de que la promesa que me devuelve **this.conseguirDatos()** se ejecuta ante y se comprueba el valor que me retorna dicha promesa.

Comment: De entrada hay un problema, si `llamada` es una función síncrona entonces al ejecutarse devolverá undefined porque el return que buscas está dentro de una función asíncrona.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/1544/54039) para que sepas porqué no puedes devolver el resultado de una promesa y cuál puede ser la alternativa.

Comment: @Lobos, cuando dices que el **return** está dentro de una función asíncrona te refieres a que está dentro del  **then()**?

Answer (score 1):

> Después tengo otra función normal cuyo nombre es llamada que debe retornar un boolean después de comprobar el estado.

Primero que nada hay que tener en claro que la función `llamada` está ejecutando una [función asíncrona](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/orphaned/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

> -Cómo y dónde debo poner el return dentro de la función llamada : dentro den "then" o fuera?

Puedes devolver un `booleano` tranquilamente en tu función `llamada()`:

```javascript
function llamada() {
  this.conseguirDatos()
    .then((valor)=>{
     //...
    });
  return true; // o false
}
```

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es que el `booleano` que devuelves sea `true` o `false` en base a la respuesta de `conseguirDatos()`, como es asíncrona, no tienes más opción que manejar la promesa como siempre.

Es decir, devolver la promesa:

```javascript
function llamada() {
  return this.conseguirDatos()
    .then((valor)=>{
       console.log("mostrando valor: " + valor);
       if(valor!=null){ // acá podrías hacer 'return valor != null' directamente :)
         return true;
       } else {
         return false;
       }
    });
}
```

Por lo tanto, si bien aclaraste que no quieres esto:

> Esta función por necesidad tiene que devolverme un boolean (por otros motivos que aquí no expongo), por lo tanto no le puedo poner un async delante

Tienes que entender que la función `llamada` depende de una función asíncrona y por eso debes manejarla como se expuso arriba.

Si quieres puedes "exponer" los motivos por el cual necesitas devolver boolean y podríamos tratar de ayudarte a encontrar una solución para tu caso.

Saludos.

Comment: El problema real que quiero resolver no está relacionado con conseguirdatos (era sólo un ejemplo ridículo). Lo que quería hacer es que una función normal de un "guard" en Angular retornase un boolean dependiendo de si otra función (que será asycn) de un servicio comprueba si un usuario está logeado en firebase con **onAuthStateChanged**

Comment: En ese caso lo mejor sería que formules una nueva pregunta con tu problema real, y no con un ejemplo "ridículo". Lo que quieres hacer en realidad es muy común y Angular lo soporta, simplemente tienes que devolver un Observable  que se complete, o una Promesa incluso, que resuelvan en `true` o `false`. Fijate en esta pregunta y si no resuelve tu problema crea una nueva y con gusto te ayudaré. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425461/angular2-canactivate-calling-async-function

Comment: Acabo de ver que habias hecho la pregunta aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/469213/uso-de-async-y-await-en-una-funci%c3%b3n-que-controla-un-guard/470608#470608 y la acabo de responder. Por favor dime si te fue de ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: Te acabo de contestar en ese hilo.